# How to add changes to code after deploying app to iPhone device

Tags: iphone

How i can make modifications to code after i deployed it on iPhone device. i only see summary, info, build settings, build phases and build rules. Don't see all project files which i can open and add changes to it.

Any ideas how to add changes after deploying and testing on real device.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a screenshot so we could see what you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are in the project or target settings. If you see a menu on the left of your screen you should be able to browse the files in your project to make changes. If you do not see that menu, then on the top right corner of the screen there should be 3 buttons with the word "View" underneath them. Click the left-most of those 3 buttons and the menu will show.

Comment: or ⌘ + O will bring toggle the navigator view.

Comment: On the left of my screen see project and target but don't see all of my files like main view controller modal view controllers files. I clicked those 3 buttons as well but nothing shows up

Comment: any ideas why i m not able to see all of my files on the left side menu

Comment: You could also try clicking the View menu and then selecting Navigators->Show Project Navigator.

Comment: thanks it worked Michael Frederick. So now i can simple make the changes to code and after saving i should be able to run on iPhone device again right

Answer (score -1):

@user1120133, if you just run the program on your device again instead of the simulator, it will automatically update everything for you.  I think that is what you mean.